# NoMethodError in Users#index [], undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using Ruby version 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.16 running on Ubuntu. I don't know what alter or update to fix this.

> NoMethodError in Users#index
>
> Showing /home/alex/Documents/curso_rails/demo_app/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:
>
> `undefined method '[]' for nil:NilClass`

Extracted source (around line #5):

```
2: 
3: 
4:   <title>DemoApp</title>
5:   <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
6:   <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
7:   <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
8:
```

Follows above, users controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @users }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/new
  # GET /users/new.json
  def new
    @user = User.new

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @user }
    end
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PUT /users/1
  # PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: "edit" }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.destroy

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end
end

Follows, `application.html.rb`

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>DemoApp</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>
  <body>

    <%= yield %>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why don't you post the `index` method from your users_controller.rb.

Comment: I added the complete files affected. Sorry I didn't do that that before, please.

Comment: please try this once and let us know if it works, replace `application.html.rb:5` to 
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "/assets/stylesheet.css" %>

Comment: chanakya devraj you solved complete my problem. Thank you so much for your kindness!